# @JoinColumns with composite primary key on both tables

Tags: hibernate, one-to-many, composite-primary-key, jpa-2.1, joincolumn

I have to map a legacy db with a couple of tables like these

```
---------
- GROUP -
---------
+idcust -
+key    -
+idgroup- 
-domain -
---------

pk(idcust,key,idgroup)

------------------
-   GROUP_LABEL  -
------------------
+idcust          -
+key             -
+idgroup         - 
+idlabel         -
-domain          -
-description_lang-
------------------

pk(idcust,key,idgroup,idlabel)
fk(idcust,key,idgroup) references group.pk
```

Both of them have composite primary keys, and the latter one's has all the fields of the first one. I cannot change the tables, so I'm stuck with mapping them as they are.

Here are the classes:

This is for the one side of the relationship

```
@Embeddable
public class GroupId implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 7202018350067509393L;

  @Column(name = "idcust")
  private String idCust;
  @Column(name = "key")
  private String key;
  @Column(name = "idgroup")
  private Long idGroup;

  //getters, setters, hashcode, equals

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "group")
public class Group{

  @EmbeddedId
  private GroupId groupId;

  @Column(name = "domain")
  private String domain;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="group", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
  private Set<GroupLabels> groupLabels;

  //getters, setters

}
```

While this is for the many side

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "group_labels")
public class GroupLabels{

    @EmbeddedId
    private GroupLabelsId groupLabelsId;

    @Column(name = "description_lang")
    private String descriptionLang;

    @Column(name = "domain")
    private String domain;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="idcust", referencedColumnName="idcust" ,insertable=false, updatable=false),
        @JoinColumn(name="key", referencedColumnName="key" ,insertable=false, updatable=false),
        @JoinColumn(name="idgroup", referencedColumnName="idgroup" ,insertable=false, updatable=false)
    })
    private Group group;

//getters, setters

}   


@Embeddable
public class GroupLabelsId implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 761043173785225772L;

    @Column(name = "idcust")
    private String idCust;
    @Column(name = "key")
    private String key;
    @Column(name = "idgroup")
    private Integer idGroup;
    @Column(name = "idlabel")
    private Integer idLabel;

//getters, setters, hashcode, equals

}
```

This mapping kind of works, as I am able to retrieve the entities, however, I took a look at the sql generated by this simple test:

```
@Test
public void testIntegrity(){
    Group got = (Group) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Group.class)
            .add(Restrictions.idEq(groupSaved.getGroupId())).uniqueResult();
    assertEquals(groupSaved.getGroupId(),got.getGroupId());

}
```

This is the sql code:

```
select
        this_.idcust as idcust1_0_1_,
        this_.idgroup as idgroup2_0_1_,
        this_.key as key3_0_1_,
        this_.domain as domain4_0_1_,
        grouplabel2_.idcust as idcust1_0_3_,
        grouplabel2_.idgroup as idgroup2_0_3_,
        grouplabel2_.key as key4_0_3_,
        grouplabel2_.idcust as idcust1_1_3_,
        grouplabel2_.idgroup as idgroup2_1_3_,
        grouplabel2_.idlabel as idlabel3_1_3_,
        grouplabel2_.key as key4_1_3_,
        grouplabel2_.idcust as idcust1_1_0_,
        grouplabel2_.idgroup as idgroup2_1_0_,
        grouplabel2_.idlabel as idlabel3_1_0_,
        grouplabel2_.key as key4_1_0_,
        grouplabel2_.description_lang as descript5_1_0_,
        grouplabel2_.domain as domain6_1_0_ 
    from
        group this_ 
    left outer join
        group_labels grouplabel2_ 
            on this_.idcust=grouplabel2_.idcust 
            and this_.idgroup=grouplabel2_.idgroup 
            and this_.key=grouplabel2_.key 
    where
        this_.idcust=? 
        and this_.key=? 
        and this_.domain=?
```

As you see it retrieves multiple times the ids of the second entity, and this makes me believe my mapping is sub optimal.

I'm using Hibernate 4.3.10 as ORM.

Is there a way I can correct the @JoinColumns to avoid multiple columns retrieve?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use @PrimaryKeyJoin

It's just a guess, I have the same issue, and I found this question but no answer, and I came across this link:
https://www.baeldung.com/java-jpa-join-vs-primarykeyjoin

I don't know if it's any better is terms of performance.